# IFS function stops working when coverting Gsheet to Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with a formula that is checking one column and adding a value to another based on that.  It works properly in Google sheets, but the IFS function is not working when i try to convert the sheet to excel. How can i make this work in Excel?

```
=IFS(I:I = "2024","9", I:I = "2025","8", I:I = "2026","7", I:I = "2027","6", I:I = "2028","5", I:I = "2029","4", I:I = "2030","3", I:I = "2031","2", I:I = "2032","1", I:I = "2033","KG", I:I = "2034","PK", I:I = "2035","P3" , I:I = "2036","P3" )
```

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: I am using version 2003 (build 126.24.20382)

Comment: Microsoft Excel for Office 365 MSO (16.0.12624.20348)

Comment: Which one?  It should work in with the office 365 subscription.  2003 does not have IFS

Comment: I think we are given Office 365 with some sort of restriction that only allows us to install Excel version 2003. It shows both versions when i check. https://i.imgur.com/4YpRbHg.png
https://i.imgur.com/5apyzAn.png

What would i use instead of an IFS statement in version 2003?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 2003 you can nest IF:

```
=IF(I2=2024,9,IF(I2=2025,8,IF(....
```

or you can use CHOOSE/MATCH

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(I2,{2024,2025,2026,...},0),9,8,7,...)
```

But each of these will need to be copied down the data set.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that upon conversion, "IFS" will be converted to "ifs". and excel does not know the "ifs" function. This is a really annoying and hard to debug.